# Honda HRV AWD, 4WD or 2WD?

Tags: honda

i m making a research to buy Honda HRV. My questions is about the wheel drive. Is it AWD, 4WD or 2WD? I dont manage to get anywhere because every article i have read is very confusing. Could any one provide a more clear answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First-generartion HR-Vs (1999-2006ish) and the second-generation (2015->) come as either 
 front-wheel drive only or in what Honda called "Real Time 4WD", which isn't a full time AWD system, instead in normal operation it's just front wheels that are driven but if the system detects that the fronts are turning faster than the rears (i.e. they are slipping/spinning) then power is transferred to the rear wheels until all four are rotating at the same speed again when it will disengage and revert to front-wheel drive.

So it's down to the individual car whether it will be permanent 2WD drive or part time 4WD - and if you want the 4WD look out for ones that are listed being "Real Time 4WD"

Comment: Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

AWD is 4WD full time no option to set it to 2WD

4WD can be set to be 2WD or 4WD.

This means the engine power can be transmitted to both front and rear drive wheels.

2WD is like most cars and trucks, only the front (or rear) wheels have power from the engine.

**A**ll **W**heel **D**rive

(Four) **4** **W**heel **D**rive

(Two) **2** **W**heel **D**rive